# Unable to initialize a customized jQuery calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, calendar

I am trying to implement a [jquery range calendar](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/jQuery-Plugin-For-Date-Range-Selector-Range-Calendar.html) to an existing project, but I am unable to make the calendar code to work in my project.

[Here](https://pastebin.com/DS1HNX8C) is the code for the calendar.

If I put this .js file as it is in my project, I get a "jQuery is not defined error", therefore is surronded the code with a function looking like this :

```
function initializeRangeCalendar($, window, undefined) {

    $.fn.rangeCalendar = function(options) {

    ...
}
```

Then I am initializing the function in one of my .ashx files in this way : 
`string init = "var init = function() { " +
            "initJUI();" +
            "if (typeof initializeRangeCalendar == 'function' ) { initializeRangeCalendar(jQuery, window); } ;" + ....`

Then, when I eventually try to call the calendar on my page I get a bunch of errors indicating that the calendar functions and variables are not defined.

Can anyone help me make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overcomplicating this, and/or misunderstanding what's required to include the code and initialise the calendar.

"jQuery not defined" suggests you haven't loaded jQuery into your page. The plugin has several dependencies including jQuery. At minimum you need to have the following code in your HTML *before* you try to add the calendar file or use it.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment-with-langs.min.js"></script>
```

Then you reference the calendar's JS and CSS files, which you should have downloaded into your site  (no need for whatever that wrapper you put round it was):

```
<script src="js/jquery.rangecalendar.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/rangecalendar.css">
```

Then create an element which will contain the calendar:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Finally intialise the plugin against the element you created above (from your example code I can't tell whether you've actually done this or not):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#demo").rangeCalendar();
});
```

You can find all of this in the instructions at http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/jQuery-Plugin-For-Date-Range-Selector-Range-Calendar.html, plus more about the possible options you can use to configure the calendar.